# My posts show 2 comment forms

Tags: comments, customization

We have a Wordpress site, [lifering.org](http://lifering.org), hosted on GoDaddy.  We recently upgraded our virtual server's Linux operating system, which involved rebuilding the site from a backup.

Now I our single posts are displaying TWO comment reply forms.  I'm sure we only had one comment reply form per post before.

I don't know how this happened - I took the backup myself - or how to fix it.

Comment: Can you share any code here? If the theme got an update, there might be a code called twice or two different functions loading a comments form.

Comment: Were you using some commenting plugin (which was not migrated) or some custom theme templates which is causing the comments method to be called twice? Can you edit the single.php file?

Answer (score 1):

Try making sure that you don't have more than one copy of Jetpack. Also try activating and deactivating Jetpack. The issue could also be in the PHP files of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is probably a theme specific issue. Look for duplicate calls to comments_template() in single.php or to comment_form() in comments.php.